# Find nid from node's internal path in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I have a path like this:

`/news/2011/05/26/some-story-path`

How do I find the nid for the node that the path points to?

**Edit**

The path above is simply a string value that I have on another page. I need to obtain information about the node that the path links to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use menu_get_object:

```
$node = menu_get_object();
```

See http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/menu_get_object/6

*edit*

I think you can specify your path like this

```
menu_get_object($type = 'node', $position = 1, $path = '/news/2011/05/26/some-story-path');
```

Comment: Thanks! I was able to query the drupal db: `SELECT src FROM url_alias WHERE dst = '$path';` and then I used `$node = menu_get_object('node', 1, $src);`

Comment: Great! I think you can use drupal_lookup_path($action='source', $path =''/news/2011/05/26/some-story-path'); instead of the custom sql query.

Answer (score 2):

In Drupal 6...

If you know the url alias, you can retrieve the internal system path:

```
$nid = str_replace("node/","",drupal_lookup_path("source","my/drupal/path"));
```

From php, when viewing/editing a node, you can also retrieve it like so:

```
function get_current_nid () {
  if (arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1)) { return arg(1); }
  return null;
}

$nid = get_current_nid();
drupal_set_message("The current node id is: $nid");
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. The path which I have (`news/2011/05/26/some-story-path`) is not the page which I am on. It is simply a string value that I have and I need to retrieve information about the node which it links to. I believe your method only works if it is on the page that is `/news/2011/05/26/some-story-path`.

Comment: No prob. You can also use drupal_lookup_path("source","news/2011/05/26/some-story-path"); to retrieve e.g. "node/123".